# REST Firebase request via qwest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, rest, firebase-realtime-database

i have a realtime database from firebase with 9386 datasets in it (but that might change in the future)

thats why i want to know whats the "key" of the last event.

thats how i'm currently trying to get it to know: (with npm module qwest)

```
    let order = "\u0022\u0024key\u0022";
    let dbUrl = "https://example.firebaseio.com/users.json?limitToLast=1&orderBy=";
    let end;
    qwest.get(dbUrl + order)
    .then(function(xhr, response) {
      console.log(response);
      end = response[9386]["username"];
      console.log(end);
    });
```

first question: why do i have to escape the quotation marks and the dollarsign?

second question: how can i get the "key" of the last item i'm checking for in the json (limitToLast=1).

json response looks like this:

```
{"9386":
 {
  "fromListA":"1",
  "fromListB":"0",
  "id":"9939",
  "lastChecked":"2019-05-09 03:18:05",
  "userid":"123456789",
  "username":"username"
 }
}
```

and i want to get the "9386" in a variabel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Since you chose to use `"` to limit the `dbUrl` string, you can't use `"` inside that string's value without escaping it. A simpler way to define the string is to use `'` to delimit it:

   ```
   let dbUrl = 'https://example.firebaseio.com/users.json?limitToLast=1&orderBy="$key"';
   ```
2. To get the key of the object, use something like:

   ```
   Object.keys(response)[0]
   ```

```js
var response = {"9386":
 {
  "fromListA":"1",
  "fromListB":"0",
  "id":"9939",
  "lastChecked":"2019-05-09 03:18:05",
  "userid":"123456789",
  "username":"username"
 }
}

console.log(Object.keys(response)[0]);
```

Comment: if i do what you said in 1. i get this error: /users.json?limitToLast=1&orderBy=%22.key%22 400 (Bad Request)

2. works fine! Thank you very much!

Comment: Ah, I had a typo there. It should be `$key` in REST API calls.

Comment: yeah thats not the problem. the problem is that it still gives Bad Request because it doesn't escape %22... i edited again and now it works... don't know what i changed though.

Comment: still doesn't work, if orderBy comes right after the question mark. got this markup now: `let db = 'https://checkblock.firebaseio.com/users.json?orderBy="$key"';` and i get the bad request error again if i try to add anything to it through options